# Is it possible to port/move scrumworks pro data to tfs

Tags: tfs

We are currently in the process of trying to migrate our users to TFS 2018. A few of them are still using Scrumworks Pro and I was wondering if there is a way to convert the data in scrumworks Pro to TFS including attachments?  I have not been able to find any posts related to this kind of move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default way or tool to migrate data from scrumworks pro to TFS. But I've noticed scrumworks pro provides api to get data. You could refer to the following link to get the data you need from scrumworks pro api:

http://www.danube.com/docs/scrumworks/pro/6.0.1/api2/index.html

And then use TFS rest api to create data. You may need to reorganize the data to fit the format:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/